# Class definition crashes in IE, but works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. is any error in class definition for IE?

Tags: javascript, class, svg

I have defined a class as:

```
//Las propiedades de un botón
class propiedadesDeBoton {
    propiedadesDeBotonconstructor(botonActual, nombreBoton, pathBorde, pathDibujoDeFondo, 
                stateButton, lastStateButton, toggleButton) {

        this.botonActual=botonActual;               //El botón;
        this.nombreBoton;                           //El nombre del botón;
        this.pathBorde=pathBorde;                   //El borde
        this.pathDibujoDeFondo=pathDibujoDeFondo;   //El dibujo del botón           
        this.stateButton=stateButton;               //El estado actual del botón
        this.lastStateButton=stateButton;           //El estado actual del botón
        this.toggleButton=toggleButton;             //Si es tobbleButton o no
    }
}
```

This class definition works without problem in Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

When I try to run in IE11, the code crashes. I can find the error in the onload function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="project" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
onload="init(evt)" 
>
```

I I remove this class definition, the code doesn't crash.

The question is: is there any error in class definition for IE?

thanks

Comment: It isnt supported ?!?

Comment: IE11 is incompatible with `class` definitions: http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Comment: It's right Jonas So... could I take any alternative?.

Comment: Try to convert your code into ES5 equivalent with online Babel transpiler (e.g. [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=Q))

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to respond myself.
Effectively, IE11 and Opera doesn't support Class definitions.

The only way I have found is to construct a matrix. I understand that isn't the best way, but...

Microsoft and Apple, the vintage...

```
function botonDeBotonera(boton,nombreBoton,stateButton,lastStateButton,
                  toggleButton,pathBorde,pathDibujoDeFondo,rel) {

    this.botonActual=boton;                                 //El botón actual (viene de parámetro de función)
    this.nombreBoton=nombreBoton;                           //El nombre del botón actual
    this.stateButton=stateButton;                           //El estado actual del botón    
    this.lastStateButton=lastStateButton;                   //El estado anterior del botón  
    this.toggleButton=toggleButton;                         //Si es tobbleButton o no   
    this.pathBorde=pathBorde;                               //El borde
    this.pathDibujoDeFondo=pathDibujoDeFondo;               //El dibujo del botón
    this.rel=rel;
}

var botonera=[];

function setPropiedadesDeBotones(botonActual,nombreBoton,stateButton,lastStateButton,
                                 toggleButton,pathBorde,pathDibujoDeFondo,rel) {

    var botonActual=botonActual;                                //El botón actual (viene de parámetro de función)
    var nombreBoton=botonActual.getAttribute("id");             //El nombre del botón actual
    var stateButton=botonActual.getAttribute("buttonstate");    //El estado actual del botón    
    var lastStateButton=botonActual.getAttribute("laststate");  //El estado anterior del botón  
    var toggleButton=botonActual.getAttribute("togglebutton");  //Si es tobbleButton o no   

    var pathBorde                                               //El borde
    var pathDibujoDeFondo                                       //El dibujo del botón           

    for (var i=0;i< botonActual.childNodes.length;i++) {        
        try {
            var pathVolatil="";
            pathVolatil=botonActual.childNodes[i];
            var idVolatil=pathVolatil.getAttribute("id");

            if (idVolatil.indexOf("borde")!=-1) {
                pathBorde=pathVolatil;
            } else if (idVolatil.indexOf("dibujo")!=-1) {
                pathDibujoDeFondo=pathVolatil;
            }

        } catch(err) {}
    }

    botonera.push(new botonDeBotonera(botonActual,nombreBoton,stateButton,lastStateButton,toggleButton,pathBorde,pathDibujoDeFondo,[]));
```